# Range restriction of n-ary relation in Alloy

Tags: alloy

I have a signature

```
abstract sig B{}

sig B1 extends B{}

sig B2 extends B{}

sig A{
 rel: B->C
}
```

How do I restrict the B of rel to be of type B1? I tried a fact `rel :> (B1 -> C)` but I get a type error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would express it as follows:

**signature fact :**

```
sig A{
 rel: B->C
}{
 rel.C in B1
}
```

**or standalone fact:**

```
fact {
 rel[A].C in B1
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. But can you please give an example of a range or domain restriction code for n-ary? I can't figure out how they work. Or point out a nice guide?

Answer (score 3):

You can only restrict the domain (i.e. the left-most set) or the range (i.e. the right-most set) of a relation. Restriction does not constrain a relation, but builds a new relation out of an existing one.

`D <: Rel` creates a new relation where the domain of `Rel` is restricted to `D`.

`Rel :> R` creates a new relation where the range of `Rel` is restricted to `R`.

To constrain the domain of `rel` in your example, you would usually use the statements given bei Loïc. Theoretically you could also use restriction for this, but that is less idiomatic:

`(B1 <: rel) = rel`